# Terraform 0.12+ Error Inappropriate value for attribute "service_account": string required with try() function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I have a module for `google_service_account`, and just converted to Terraform-12 (0.12.24)

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  count        = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  account_id   = var.account_id
  display_name = var.display_name
}
```

```
output.tf retrieves the email

output "email" {
  value = try(google_service_account.service_account.*.email, null)
  # value = element( --> Commented out part works fine
  #   concat(google_service_account.service_account.*.email, [""]),
  #   0,
  # )
  description = "The e-mail address of the service account. Usually use this when constructing IAM policies."
```

When using this module in another resource as follows

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "registry_bucket_iam" {
  bucket = "artifacts.${var.project}.appspot.com"
  role   = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  member = "serviceAccount:${module.k8s-node-service-account.email}"
}
```

I get the following error

```
  48:   member = "serviceAccount:${module.k8s-node-service-account.email}"
    |----------------
    | module.k8s-node-account.email is tuple with 1 element

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

How can this be resolved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`google_service_account.service_account.*.email` evaluates to an array of 1 or 0 elements dependeing on `var.enabled` -  while `google_service_account.service_account[0].email` evaluates to a `string` or to an error if `var.enabled` is `false`. So when using `try()` you want to evaluate to the `string` or in case of an error default to `null`

changing your output to the following should lead to the expected result of having an email output of type `string`.

```
output "email" {
  value = try(google_service_account.service_account[0].email, null)
}
```

Comment: This above worked, only thing I have to change was to evaluate to empty string `""` instead of `null` incase it was an error